# How to querying and filtering efficiently on Fauna DB?

Tags: faunadb

For example, let’s assume we have a collection with hundreds of thousands of documents of clients with 3 fields, name, monthly_salary, and age.

How can I search for documents that monthly_salary is higher than 2000 and age higher than 30?

In SQL this would be straightforward but with Fauna, I´m struggling to understand the best approach because terms of Index only work with an exact match. I see in docs that I can use the Filter function but I would need to get all documents in advance so it looks a bit counterintuitive and not performant.

Below is an example of how I can achieve it, but not sure if it’s the best approach, especially if it contains a lot of records.

```
Map(
  Filter(
    Paginate(Documents(Collection('clients'))),
    Lambda(
      'client',
      And(
        GT(Select(['data', 'monthly_salary'], Get(Var('client'))), 2000),
        GT(Select(['data', 'age'], Get(Var('client'))), 30),
        )
      )
    ),
    Lambda(
      'filteredClients',
      Get(Var('filteredClients'))
      )
  
  )
```

Is this correct or I´m missing some fundamental concepts about Fauna and FQL?
can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Efficient searching is performed using Indexes.  You can check out the docs for [search with Indexes](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/indexes/search), and [there is a "cookbook"](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/cookbook/search/) for some different search examples.

There are two ways to use Indexes to search, and which one you use depends on if you are searching for *equality* (exact match) or *inequality* (greater than or less than, for example).

## Searching for *equality*

If you need an exact match, then use Index **terms**.  This is most explicit in the docs, and it is also not what your original question is about, so I am not going to dwell much here.  But here is a simple example

given user documents with this shape

```js
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("User"), "1234"),
  ts: 16934907826026,
  data: {
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "jdoe@example.com,
    age: 50,
    monthly_salary: 3000
  }
}
```

and an index defined like the following

```js
CreateIndex({
  name: "users_by_email",
  source: Collection("User"),
  terms: [ { field: ["data", "email"] } ],
  unique: true // user emails are unique
})
```

You can search for exact matches with... the [`Match` function](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/match)!

```js
Get(
  Match(Index("user_by_email"), "jdoe@example.com")
)
```

## Searching for *inequality*

Searching for inequalities is more interesting and also complicated.  It requires using Index **values** and the [`Range` function](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/range?).

Keeping with the document above, we can create a new index

```js
CreateIndex({
  name: "users__sorted_by_monthly_salary",
  source: Collection("User"),
  values: [ 
    { field: ["data", "monthly_salary"] },
    { field: ["ref"] }
  ]
})
```

Note that I've not defined any `terms` in the above Index.  The important thing for inequalities is again the `values`.  We've also included the ref as a value, since we will need that later.

Now we can use `Range` to get all users with salary in a given range.  This query will get all users with salary starting at 2000 and all above.

```js
Paginate(
  Range(
    Match(Index("users__sorted_by_monthly_salary")),
    [2000],
    []
  )
)
```

## Combining Indexes

For "OR" operations, use the [`Union` function](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/union).
For "AND" operations, use the [`Intersection` function](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/intersection).

Functions like `Match` and `Range` return Sets.  A really important part of this is to make sure that when you "combine" Sets with functions like `Intersection`, that the shape of the data is the same.

Using sets with the same shape is not difficult for Indexes with no `values`, they default to the same single ref value.

```js
Paginate(
  Intersection(
    Match(Index("user_by_age"), 50), // type is Set<Ref>
    Match(Index("user_by_monthly_salary, 3000) // type is Set<Ref>
  )
)
```

When the Sets have different shapes they need to be modified or else the Intersection will never return results

```js
Paginate(
  Intersection(
    Range(
      Match(Index("users__sorted_by_age")),
      [30],
      []
    ), // type is Set<[age, Ref]>
    Range(
      Match(Index("users__sorted_by_monthly_salary")),
      [2000],
      []
    ) // type is Set<[salary, Ref]>
  )
)

{
  data: [] // Intersection is empty
}
```

So how do we change the shape of the Set so they can be intersected?  We can use the [`Join` function](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/join), along with the [`Singleton` function](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/singleton).

`Join` will run an operation over all entries in the Set.  We will use that to return only a ref.

```js
Join(
  Range(Match(Index("users__sorted_by_age")), [30], []),
  Lambda(["age", "ref"], Singleton(Var("ref")))
)
```

Altogether then:

```js
Paginate(
  Intersection(
    Join(
      Range(Match(Index("users__sorted_by_age")), [30], []),
      Lambda(["age", "ref"], Singleton(Var("ref")))
    ),
    Join(
      Range(Match(Index("users__sorted_by_monthly_salary")), [2000], []),
      Lambda(["age", "ref"], Singleton(Var("ref")))
    )
  )
)
```

### tips for combining indexes

You can use additional logic to combine different indexes when different terms are provided, or search for missing fields using bindings.  Lot's of cool stuff you can do.

Do check out the [cook book](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/cookbook/search/) and the [Fauna forums](https://forums.fauna.com/c/help-general/8) as well for ideas.

## BUT WHY!!!

It's a good question!

Consider this:  Since Fauna is served as a serverless API, you get charged for each individual read and write on your documents and indexes as well as the compute time to execute your query.  SQL can be much easier, but it is a much higher level language.  Behind SQL sits a query planner making assumptions about how to get you your data.  If it cannot do it efficiently it may default to scanning your entire table of data or otherwise performing an operation much more expensive than you might have expected.

With Fauna, YOU are the query planner.  That means it is much more complicated to get started, but it also means you have fine control over the performance of you database and thus your cost.

We are working on improving the experience of defining schemas and the indexes you need, but at the moment you do have to define these queries at a low level.